# Big-O: Getting all of the keys in a Java HashMap

Tags: java, amortized-analysis

Anyone know what the amortized analysis is of keySet in Java HashMap?  `O(1)`?

Is iterating through them `O(n)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map.keySet()` simply returns a reference to the key set which is stored in the map, so it clearly is an O(1) operation.

The iteration is then a loop over that set, which itself internally uses a loop over the map's buckets, so the operation takes a time proportional to n+m where n is the size of the keyset and m the capacity of the map.

So if your map has a very large capacity with only one entry, an iteration over keySet will loop over all the buckets even if there is only one key.

Not sure how you translate that in big-o notation.

I just ran a quick test with 2 maps, with one entry each. One map has a capacity of 10 millions, the other a capacity of 1. The iteration over the keyset (one item in both cases) takes 3,500 times more time with the large map (18,843,092 ns vs 5434 ns).

ps: it is similar to what the [javadoc of HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) says:

> Iterating over this set requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

Comment: +1 If you use LinkedHashMap iteration is O(n) regardless of the capacity.

Comment: @assylias Can you plz explain this "The iteration is then a loop over that set, which itself internally uses a loop over the map's buckets,". may be an explanation of this line will be [an answer  to my question][(What the iteration cost on a HashSet also depend on the capacity of backing map?)]

Comment: @Geek not sure which part you don't understand. `for (Key k : map.keyset())` is an iteration over the keyset, which happens to be a set. This is equivalent to using an iterator. And if you look at the code of the set's iterator, you will see that it loops over each map bucket, whatever the number of items in the set. So if the set has only one item, but the map has 10,000,000 items, iterating over the set will mean iterating over the 10,000,000 map's buckets, to fetch only one item.

Comment: @assylias +1 for the clarification. It helped me accept the answer to my question . But why is it not n*m and instead n+m ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.keySet%28%29) for the keySet.

Iterating through a Set is O(n) based in [this](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)

Comment: Posting answers that rely on links is not a good practice. If one or more of your links stops working(like 1 is for me right now), it destroys the future use of your answer.