# What the iteration cost on a HashSet also depend on the capacity of backing map?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable, time-complexity

From the JavaDocs of [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations
>   (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses
>   the elements properly among the buckets. Iterating over this set
>   requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size
>   (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap
>   instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set
>   the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if
>   iteration performance is important

Why does iteration takes time proportional to the sum(number of elements in set+ capacity of backing map)  and not only to the number of elements in the set itself ?

.

Comment: How would you iterate over all the elements without also iterating over all the empty buckets?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903357/829571

Comment: You can also [check the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashSet.java?av=f#168) and drill down to see what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`HashSet` is imlemented using a `HashMap` where the elements are the map keys. Since a map has a defined number of buckets that can contain one or more elements, iteration needs to check each bucket, whether it contains elements or not.

Comment: what are the values of that hashmap ?

Comment: @Geek since the values don't matter they're just dummy objects (or more precisely, it's one dummy object: `private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();`).

Answer (score 3):

Using LinkedHashSet follows the "linked" list of entries so the number of blanks doesn't matter. Normally you wouldn't have a HashSet where the capacity is much more than double the size actually used.  Even if you do, scanning a million entries, mostly `null` doesn't take much time (milli-seconds)

Comment: 2 ms for each 1 million null on my machine ;-)

Comment: @assylias Sounds about right.  Iterating over a HashSet isn't going to be pretty no matter what you do. Really you want to do some lookup or sorted collection where you are only working on a few entries if you want speed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does iteration takes time proportional to the sum(number of
>   elements in set+ capacity of backing map) and not only to the number
>   of elements in the set itself ?

The elements are dispersed inside the underlying `HashMap` which is backed by an array.
So it is not known which buckets are occupied (but it is known how many elements are totally available).
 So to iterate over all elements ***all*** buckets must be checked

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the time it takes to iterate around the set, and you are using Java 6 or greater take a look at this beauty:

[ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)